# Radius of circle tangent to larger circle intersecting smaller circle at specified angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

As shown below in the image I know the radius an outer circle and an inner circle and an angle(green).  I drew a red arc which is tangential to the outer circle and terminates at the intersections of the 60 degree angle and the inner circle.  Knowing only these two radii and the angle how can I calculate the arc length of the red arc?
Edit: I labeled the radius of the red arc in the image however I only know it because I drew the arc in autocad.

![Example Image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsWEB.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there is a circle that passes through $D$ and $C$, i.e. a circle centered at $B$ with radius  $BC = BD$.

[image]

Given radii of outer circle $AD = AB+BD = 38.5$, inner circle $AC = 35.5$, and angle $\angle CAD = \angle CAB = 30$. Then using Law of Cosines

$$(BC)^2 = (AB)^2 + (CA)^2-2(CA)(AB)\cos(\angle CAB)$$

Let $x = BD = BC$. Then $x^2 = (38.5-x)^2 + 35.5^2 -2 \cdot 35.5 \cdot (38.5-x)\cos(30)$, which is a degree one equation with solution $x = 24.188$

Hence radius equals $24.188$. It remains to determine angle for lines joining the arc.

Using Law of Cosines again to determine angle $\angle ABC$, and note that $AB = AD - 24.188$. Then,

$$\angle CBD = 180 - \arccos(\frac{(AB)^2 + (BC)^2 - (AC)^2}{2 (AB)(BC)}) = 47.2$$

The arc length of $DC$ is thus $\angle CBD \cdot \frac{2 \pi}{360} \cdot BC = 19.926$

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is indeed what I'm looking for however I'm having trouble with the first order equation.  I'm having trouble solving for x.  Could you walk me through that equation?  I believe the rest of it I understand.

Comment: $-x^2 + 38.5^2-2\cdot 38.5 \cdot x + x^2 + 35.5^2 - 2 \cdot 35.5 \cdot 38.5 \cos(30) + 2 \cdot 35.5 \cdot x \cos(30) = 0$. Note $-x^2+x^2 =0$ and this amounts to solving $ax + b= 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I give you an analytic solution.

Put your circles in reference system that ha s as $x$ axis the bisector of the angle of $60°$ and let $r_1<r_2$ the radii of the two given circles. Than the point of tangency of the arc is $Q=(x_Q,y_Q)=(r_2,0)$ and the upper point of intersection with the smaller circle is $P=(x_P,y_P)=\left(\dfrac{r_1\sqrt 3}{2},\dfrac{r_1}{2}\right)$.

By symmetry, the arc stay on a circle that has center in a point $C=(\alpha,0)$ of equation $ (x-\alpha)^2 +y^2=r^2$.

Substituting the coordinates of $P$ and $Q$ in this equation you can find $\alpha$ and $r$.

The leght of the arc is:
$$
2\int_{x_P}^{x_Q} \sqrt{r^2-(x-\alpha)^2}dx
$$